# Understanding the Spring Data JPA @NoRepositoryBean interface

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I encountered the `@NoRepositoryBean` interface several times whilst reading the Spring Data documentation.

To quote from the documentation:

> If you're using automatic repository interface detection using the
>   Spring namespace using the interface just as is will cause Spring
>   trying to create an instance of MyRepository. This is of course not
>   desired as it just acts as indermediate between Repository and the
>   actual repository interfaces you want to define for each entity. To
>   exclude an interface extending Repository from being instantiated as
>   repository instance annotate it with `@NoRepositoryBean`.

However, I am still not sure when and where to use it. Can someone please advise and give me a concrete usage example?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The annotation is used to avoid creating repository proxies for interfaces that actually match the criteria of a repo interface but are not intended to be one. It's only required once you start going into extending all repositories with functionality. Let me give you an example:

Assume you'd like to add a method foo() to all of your repositories. You would start by adding a repo interface like this

```
public interface com.foobar.MyBaseInterface<…,…> extends CrudRepository<…,…> {

  void foo();
}
```

You would also add the according implementation class, factory and so on. You concrete repository interfaces would now extend that intermediate interface:

```
public interface com.foobar.CustomerRepository extends MyBaseInterface<Customer, Long> {

}
```

Now assume you bootstrap - let's say Spring Data JPA - as follows:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foobar" />
```

You use `com.foobar` because you have `CustomerRepository` in the same package. The Spring Data infrastructure now has no way to tell that the `MyBaseRepository` is not a concrete repository interface but rather acts as intermediate repo to expose the additional method. So it would try to create a repository proxy instance for it and fail. You can now use `@NoRepositoryBean` to annotate this intermediate interface to essentially tell Spring Data: don't create a repository proxy bean for this interface.

That scenario is also the reason why `CrudRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository` carry this annotation as well. If the package scanning picked those up by accident (because you've accidentally configured it this way) the bootstrap would fail.

Long story short: use the annotation to prevent repository interfaces from being picked up as candidates to end up as repository bean instances eventually.

Comment: What a precise and perfect example to demonstrate the concept!! Thank you Oliver!

Comment: if `MyBaseInterface` is not annotated with any annotations like `@Repository` etc.. should not that be sufficient. Coz spring would not have any way to know that this is a spring component as there are no component annotations.

Answer (score 9):

We can declare a new interface as our custom method:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findByAttributeContainsText(String attributeName, String text);
}
```

Our interface extends the JpaRepository interface so that we'll benefit from all the standard behavior.

You'll also notice we added the @NoRepositoryBean annotation. This is necessary because otherwise, the default Spring behavior is to create an implementation for all subinterfaces of Repository.

```
public interface ExtendedStudentRepository extends ExtendedRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

Comment: if `ExtendedRepository` is not annotated with any annotations like `@Repository` etc.. should not that be sufficient. Coz spring would not have any way to know that this is a spring component as there are no component annotations.