# Spring Failed to Autowiring because of proxy-target-class="true" and <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop, autowired, proxy-classes

I have the following spring configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled"  pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

<tx:annotation-driven  />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.web,com.security" />
```

i have enabled proxy-target-class in global-method-security, because i want use @PreAuthorize annotation in the **controller** (i aware that spring team doesn't encourage this),
and using aop aspectJ as 'interceptor' in **service** when saving an object.

it seem that because the proxy configuration in global-method-security enabled and the default aop aspectj is using proxy implementation. it failed to autowiring the bean in all controller. proxying proxy ?

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add")
@PreAuthorize("@securityPermission.validatePermission()")
public String add(Model model) {
   //codes
}
```

my service class with @Aspect annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Aspect
@Service
public class InterceptorServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImplementation implements InterceptorService {
@Autowired
    private LogRepository logRepository;

@Around("execution(* com.repository.CardRequestRepository.save(..))")
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class,timeout = 30)
   public Object checkProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
   LOGGER.info("SERVICE : START Process checking Interceptor");

}
```

error logs :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'approvalActivityController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.csl.cms.service.ApprovalActivityService com.csl.cms.web.ApprovalActivityController.approvalActivityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'approvalActivityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.csl.cms.repository.CardRequestRepository com.csl.cms.service.serviceimplementasi.ApprovalActivityServiceImpl.cardRequestRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardRequestRepository': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy572]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy572
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:376)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy572]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy572
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy572
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
    ... 72 more
```

repository class

```
public interface CardRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<CardRequest, Long>, CardRequestRepositoryCustom {
public List<CardRequest> findByCardholderId(Long cardholderId);

@Query("Select cr FROM CardRequest cr "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH cr.cardholder ch "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH ch.identityDocument "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH cr.program p "
        + "WHERE cr.id = :id")
public CardRequest findOneFetching(@Param("id") Long cardholderId);
```

}

```
public interface CardRequestRepositoryCustom {

    public List<CardRequest> findCardRequestWithDatatablesCriterias(DatatablesCriterias criterias);
.....
```

service impl class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Service
public class ApprovalActivityServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImplementasi implements ApprovalActivityService {

    @Autowired
    private ApprovalActivityRepository approvalActivityRepository;
    ...
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public ApprovalActivity findOne(Long id) {
        LOGGER.info("SERVICE : ApprovalActivity findOne id =" + id);
        return approvalActivityRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

baseserviceimpl class

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImplementasi
  implements Serializable
{
  protected transient Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
}
```

is it possible using aop:aspectj-autoproxy and enable proxy-target-class at same time ? or anyone have another suggestion ? :)

**Failed Autowire Issue resolved**

as suggestion from @M.Deinum i resolved my autowiring issue, added proxy-target-class="true" attribute in :

```
<tx:annotation-driven /> 
<cache:annotation-driven />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

and i remove @Service in the class with @Aspect annotation.

note : in the InterceptorServiceImpl i was using @Service because i want @Autowiring to call repository/service bean

**aspect class issue that occurred :**

it seem because i have removed the @Service annotation in my aspect class, the aop aspectj somehow did not executed, and no error in my logs.

Comment: The stack-trace indicates the error is in code you have not shown. Please post the code for `CardRequestRepository` and `ApprovalActivityServiceImpl`

Comment: Why is your `@Aspect` a `@Service` ?! Seems a bit unnatural. When using proxies and one of them specifies `proxy-target-class="true"` everything will use class based proxies. You can try to set everything to `proxy-target-class="true"`.

Comment: @geoand i have added the repository class and serviceImpl class, and i think there is no relevance with the my proxy issue.

Comment: @satrioaditya Does `BaseServiceImplementasi` autowire `CardRequestRepository` perhaps? Can you show it's code?

Comment: @geoand i have added the code, but actually it only contains logger, there is no autowire in the class

Comment: @satrioaditya The stack-trace indicated that there should exist a field `ApprovalActivityServiceImpl` in `ApprovalActivityServiceImpl` but I don't see it in your code. What gives?

Comment: It looks like Spring takes a JDK proxy of a bean named `cardRequestRepository`. May be you know why and you should elaborate on that. But it also needs to take a CGLIB proxy of it. Is there any security annotation there, and what is `cardRequestRepository` ?

Comment: resolved my autowiring issue, and i got another problem :), my aspect class did not executed.

Comment: @SergeBallesta CardRequestRepository is my aop pointcut class. i still doesnt have a clue why it failed autowiring the CardRequestRepository bean

Comment: @SergeBallesta my CardRequestRepository extends JpaRepository (i`m using data jpa). and i found that JpaRepository extends CrudRepository, and have @NoRepositoryBean annotation, it seems because that annotation repository proxy bean cant be created [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11585811/1982376) 
[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html)

Comment: I do not thing the problem is there, the @NoRepositoryBean annotation has to be placed on intermediary interfaces.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I changed the pointcut class with a class that does not extend jpaRepository, and apparently it works. the issue when autowiring did not occur, and my aop class was executed properly.

and i only enabled the proxy for global-security-method.

Comment: I think you should effectivly use dedicated classes for your aspects, as suggested by M. Deinum ...

Answer (score 4):

I resolved my issue, it seem because the using of data jpa (JpaRepository) in my repository class.
here is my xml configuration :

```
<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/> //enabled proxy to use @preAuthorize in controller
<tx:annotation-driven />
<cache:annotation-driven />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xxx.service.serviceimplementasi" />  
<jpa:repositories  base-package="com.csl.cms.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"  />
```

data jpa configs :

```
<!--Spring Data JPA Configuration-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource-1" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.xxx.entity"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" /> 
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />        
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

repository class :

```
public interface CardRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<CardRequest, Long>, CardRequestRepositoryCustom {
    public List<CardRequest> findByCardholderId(Long cardholderId);
```

in CardRequestRepositoryCustom class, create a custom save method using entityManager, so it will not depends on JpaRepository class.

```
public class CardRequestRepositoryImpl implements CardRequestRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

 @Override
    public CardRequest customSave(CardRequest cardRequest) {
       em.persist(cardRequest);
       return cardRequest;
    }
```

i also changed my point cut class in my aspect class, use the repository custom class :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Aspect
@Component
public class ApprovalInterceptorServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImplementasi implements ApprovalInterceptorService {

    @Autowired
    private LifecycleLogRepository lifecycleLogRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ApprovalDefinitionRepository approvalDefinitionRepository;
    @Around("execution(* com.xxx.xxx.repository.repositoryimplementasi.CardRequestRepositoryImpl.customSave(..))")
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class,timeout = 30)
    public CardRequest checkApprovalProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    LOGGER.info("SERVICE : START Approval Process checking Interceptor");
                System.out.println("SERVICE : START Approval Process checking Interceptor");

                Object messageParam[] = new Object[1];
        Object[] objs = joinPoint.getArgs();
        CardRequest cardRequest = (CardRequest) objs[0];
```

....

in the aop aspect class, using @Component to autowiring the service bean and do not extends the repository class using jpaRepository, instead use/create a custom repository class and entityManager to save an object. with this configuration and codes my proxy class problem fixed.

if i applied  @Component, @Autowired and using jpaRepository in my aspect class, the repository bean class failed to autowiring. still does not know why it happen.