# How to use generics with JpaRepository of spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
//generic repo
public interface MyGenericRepo extends JpaRepository<GenericEntity,Integer> { }

//entity
class Place extends GenericEntity {
    private Event event;
}

//entity
class Event extends GenericEntity{  }

//entity
class Offer extends GenericEntity
{
    private Place place;
}

//entity
class User extends GenericEntity {
    private Place place;
}
```

what should I take in GenericEntity and how to create a ModelManager to save and load entities

Comment: yes its similar but how to create  service please

Answer (score 3):

If you wan't create your own repository interface with `Integer` as a key. You have to difine:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyGenericRepo<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
}
```

annotation `@NoRepositoryBean` is needed to avoid creation of Repository implementation. You can read more on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585811/3058413.

After it you should difive interface for each entity:

```
public interface PlaceRepository extends MyGenericRepo<Place> {

}
```

Spring data automatically will create implementation of this repostory.

Comment: i dont want to create repository per entity

Comment: You cannot generify entity class cause spring won't be able to terminate with entity it must use.

Comment: if any example please