# Spring data repository - common method for all repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using Spring boot 2 with Reactive repository for executing stored proc which will return the count. I have 30 stored proc and all of them will just return a number and takes no arguments.

So created a model for stored proc StroedProcDomain.java and one sample repository as below.

```
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<StroedProcDomain, Long> {

    @Query("CALL JOB_LOAD()")
    Mono<Integer> executeProc();

}
```

Need to create 30 such repositories and would like to enforce all the repositories to use the same method

> Mono<Integer> executeProc()

But the stored proc name will be different. So @Query will be different for each repository.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Currently, I have 30 repositories. Would like to have a base repository so as to force the method name.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to force the method name on an interface. To have a base repository, you can define an interface and use @NoRepositoryBean on it then extend it, however this mean the Query annotation has to be put on the base interface method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576831/understanding-the-spring-data-jpa-norepositorybean-interface

Comment: Is it possible to pass the query thru param and have only one method in the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could put a two methods on a common interface: your actual query method, which would be implemented by a [custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) calling the stored procedure, plus a method that provides just the name of the stored procedure.

But this would be considerable more code and more complex code than just an annotated query method on each repository.